# JSON serialize to a different value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the below json which im serializing

```
{
"name":"John",
"switch":"1"
},
{
"name":"Jim",
"switch":"0"
}
```

I want to serialize it to a differnt name So I had to do it like below

```
class Data {
    private String name;
    private String flag;
    @JsonProperty("flag")
    public byte getFlag() {
      return flag;
    }

    @JsonProperty("switch")
    public void setSwitch(String s) {
      this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

So that I get it converted as below

```json
{
"name":"John",
"flag":"1"
},
{
"name":"Jim",
"flag":"0"
}
```

Now I wanted to map the numic values to Y and N for 1 and 0 respectively. Can I acheive that ?

Im expecting my final string to be like this

```
{
"name":"John",
"switch":"Y"
},
{
"name":"Jim",
"switch":"N"
}
```

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the getter. However I'd recommend not doing this at all and rather transform your business class into another one that represents your JSON model. _IMHO_

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Gaël J, but still if you want to go ahead this code change might help you to convert that 1/0 to Y/N.

```
public class Application {

    @ToString
    static class Input {

        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String name;

        @JsonProperty("switch")
        private String flag;

        @JsonProperty("name")
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        @JsonProperty("switch")
        public void setSwitch(String s) {
            for(SwitchMap valuePair : SwitchMap.values()){
                if(valuePair.getValue().equals(s)){
                    this.flag = valuePair.name();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "\"name\":\"John\",\n" +
                "\"switch\":\"1\"\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Input in = mapper.readValue(json, Input.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(in));
    }
}
```

define an enum with the mapping

```
@Getter
public enum SwitchMap {

    Y("1"),
    N("0");

    private final String value;

    private SwitchMap(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```